# Default download directory Edge web driver - powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am looking to use Selenium EdgeOptions prefs capability ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options#edgeoptions-object ) to set the download location. Prefs is a dictionary so I am essentially just looking to get the syntax right, which I have not yet been able to. I am not sure if I need to turn the prefs dictionary into a PowerShell hash table first or not?

Code so far:

```
$options = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions
$options.AddAdditionalEdgeOption("prefs", {"download.default_directory" ; "C:\temp"})
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver($options)
```

Something is incorrect in the middle line as I am not sure the syntax to update this value in the nested dictionary that is 'prefs'. It is nested because 'download' is also a dictionary.

Edit:

I am now using the AddAdditionalCapability() method which does not throw any errors when running the script now. However the download location is still not successfully changed via the commands below:

```
$options = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions
$options.AddAdditionalCapability('prefs', @{'download' = @{'default_directory' = "C:\temp"} } )
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver($options)
```

[this solution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546738/default-download-directory-edge-web-driver-python) is what I am trying to acomplish but in PowerShell. I am using Selenium version 3. I have thought about updating to version 4 but I am not sure that is available with EdgeDriver yet? I have found most EdgeDriver documentation to be slightly inconsistent with method and property names.
So, ultimately I am not sure where this code is going wrong, whether it is due to some syntax or other issue. For example this [Microsoft EdgeDriver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options#webviewoptions-object) says the 'AddAdditionalEdgeOption' method is how one would  change the download location. But when I call

```
$options | Get-Member
```

I find that the method which I believe I need to use is called 'AddAdditionalCapability'. I am assuming this discrepancy is due to different selenium or edgedriver versions but I cannot confirm that anywhere.

Anywho, if anyone has ever used selenium and edgedriver to change the default download location using PowerShell (I am assuming atleast one person out there has done this haha) I would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: You need to upgrade to Selenium 4 as Selenium 3 is no longer supported. You can also check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#using-selenium-4): *To use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge, if you use Selenium, you must use Selenium 4, which has built-in support for Microsoft Edge (Chromium).*

Comment: This should still be possible with Selenium 3. I would like to accomplish changing the download folder in Selenium 3 if that is possible, before updating to Selenium 4. Our company servers will need to go to other steps first to be able to upgrade to selenium 4 and further update all our scripts to use the updated syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- **None of the methods below work** - this answer is therefore only (somewhat) helpful in that you'll know what *not* to try.
- For those willing to dig into the source code, here is the [definition of the `.AddAdditionalEdgeOption()` method](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/4d70bd80f40592c12170ca8382d54064278add6f/dotnet/src/webdriver/Edge/EdgeOptions.cs#L101), which shows that the second parameter is `object`-typed.

---

If "dictionary" in the [linked help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options#edgeoptions-object) refers to a .NET object that implements the `IDictionary` interface, then you should be able to use a PowerShell [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal:

```bash
$options.AddAdditionalEdgeOption(
 'prefs', 
 @{ 'savefile.default_directory' = 'C:\temp' }
)
```

Note that the `default_directory` property is nested inside the top-level `savefile` property, not `download` (at least based on the JSON found in `"$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences"`).

Given this *nesting*, the question is whether this nesting is indeed to be expressed as a property name expressing a property *path*, as above, or whether you must actually pass a *nested dictionary* (the linked help topic provides no guidance):

```bash
$options.AddAdditionalEdgeOption(
 'prefs', 
 @{ savefile = @{ default_directory = 'C:\temp' } }
)
```

Conceivably, the dictionary must be passed *as a JSON string*, which you can construct from your hashtable via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json):

```bash
$options.AddAdditionalEdgeOption(
 'prefs', 
 (@{ savefile = @{ default_directory = 'C:\temp' } } | ConvertTo-Json)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both methods and neither seemed to work unfortunately. I would think one of the two would be correct but that doesn't seem to be the case for my code atlest. Also from the Edge preferences file I have locally, I see the default_directory key under both savefile and download nested dictionaries. Hopefully you see this too?

Comment: @DizzleBeans, another thing you can try is to pass a _JSON string_ - please see my update.

Comment: Darn, that addition did not work with either method. How can in confirm my 'Preferences' file is a json like you mention? Mine is located in C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences where the data type is just listed as a 'File' ?

Comment: @DizzleBeans, you need to look a the _content_ of that file (open it in a text editor, for instance, or - in PS v7+ only - pretty-print it with `Get-Content -Raw "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences" | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashTable | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10`

Comment: Yes I have the file open in a text editor. Nevertheless, passing it as a JSON string did not seem to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DizzleBeans, I'm out of ideas. I've added a link to the source code to the answer. I found https://stackoverflow.com/q/72572072/45375, which is Python-based and does use a Python dictionary, with the same property path as you tried with (`download.default_directory`), but it calls `add_experimental_option()`. Have you tried the above with `download.default_directory`?

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions. I've tried all combinations of the above using both download.default_directory and savefile.default_directory.. Also tried add_experimental_option() instead of AddAdditionalEdgeOption() but no luck. I am fairly certain the latest version of EdgeOptions uses AddAdditionalEdgeOption() and not add_experimental_option(). Will keep trying and hoping someone stops by this post knowing how to accomplish this. I thought it was just a syntax issue I am having, and considering none of the syntax you suggested worked, maybe it is actually not a syntax issue?